# Apache CURL error SSL: CA certificate set, but certificate verification is disabled

Tags: php, apache, ssl, curl, https

Issue: My dev environment is creating this error everything I submit a login form that is using CURL. CURL is producing this error which I believe is association to the certificates generated for the SSL connection.

**My dev environment is:**

- Mac OS X Capitan 10.11
- Apache 2.4 / PHP 7.0.12

**phpinfo() states:**

- cURL: enabled / 7.50.3 / SSL: Yes / Protocols: dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, ldaps, pop3, pop3s, rtsp, scp, sftp, smb, smbs, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp / SSL Version: SecureTransport / ZLib Version: 1.2.5 / libSSH Version: libssh2/1.4.3
- OpenSSL: enabled / Library Version: OpenSSL 1.0.2h 3 May 2016 / header Version: OpenSSL 1.0.2h 3 May 2016 / openssl.cafile: (local) /usr/local/php5/ssl/certs/cacert.pem and (master) /usr/local/php5/ssl/certs/cacert.pem

In order to create the SSL setup I followed this [Enable SSL in Apache (OSX)](https://gist.github.com/nrollr/4daba07c67adcb30693e) article to a tee which eliminates browser requests and allows me to pull requests for projects that involves say Twitter etc that require SSL connections even in dev environments.

However, PHP 5.6. I had originally used to develop this specific project and as of recent I upgraded to 7 which has now caused this error.

In terms of testing the certificates, in terminal it shows the error as per the below:

```
echo | openssl s_client -connect localhost:443
```

The above command produced:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 C = AU, ST = New South Wales, L = Sydney, O = localhost, CN = localhost
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 C = AU, ST = New South Wales, L = Sydney, O = localhost, CN = localhost
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=AU/ST=New South Wales/L=Sydney/O=localhost/CN=localhost
   i:/C=AU/ST=New South Wales/L=Sydney/O=localhost/CN=localhost
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=AU/ST=New South Wales/L=Sydney/O=localhost/CN=localhost
issuer=/C=AU/ST=New South Wales/L=Sydney/O=localhost/CN=localhost
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Server Temp Key: ECDH, B-571, 570 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 1666 bytes and written 513 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: 8B39BE1C255BDD6ED6E42E85612AB24C9CD1CB2195676A2CAEA7E3FAE0E65D68
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 86DCCE7468DE39C619A64AC7C08E6F3AA55B02DC025564D4E67C7BCDDE90415D518D780FB4EEB98A69DF785ED62FFB09
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 300 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - e0 da 63 c7 3d b0 eb 5c-0b 30 c8 0f 8f 43 b2 5e   ..c.=..\.0...C.^
    0010 - 93 49 cb 87 c5 f8 a5 f4-42 bf 19 e1 16 3d 24 73   .I......B....=$s
    0020 - ab 0a 76 b9 a7 84 1b 1b-ad 3f 4b 2d 60 c7 0c 8a   ..v......?K-`...
    0030 - 3d e8 0d b2 29 db 95 b0-a6 e6 49 f6 60 3c fe 1d   =...).....I.`<..
    0040 - c2 f5 51 8f 40 ae 93 ac-f2 eb b9 99 2c c5 f0 45   ..Q.@.......,..E
    0050 - bb d7 16 a7 0f a5 52 c7-c4 b8 e4 6a 05 ab a0 25   ......R....j...%
    0060 - 9c 44 dc 15 8c 0e cf 69-18 f8 dd 8d f1 ad 21 32   .D.....i......!2
    0070 - f5 f9 d6 54 37 87 46 6d-9e 4f d2 8a 3e 16 e2 1a   ...T7.Fm.O..>...
    0080 - 41 1a 26 27 31 83 f1 ad-31 26 ab 22 17 84 50 ae   A.&'1...1&."..P.
    0090 - 06 ef 51 9e f4 40 0f 48-8b a9 66 26 1f d8 32 88   ..Q..@.H..f&..2.
    00a0 - 46 19 a2 97 44 26 9c b1-b0 15 5c 0b 02 d7 23 ea   F...D&....\...#.
    00b0 - 07 b6 72 57 b7 47 ee 9a-85 fe 16 d4 59 8d b8 34   ..rW.G......Y..4

    Start Time: 1478128414
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
---
DONE
```

For the login page that is producing this error, I am using Auth0.com and I refuse to change the CURL request verifypeer = false to suppress this error as the error is clearly identifying leakage. As developers, we want to replicate our development environment as much as possible to ensure nothing is left behind when moving to production.

Thank you and hope I have covered everything necessary here. I don't use external packages such as MAMP or XAMPP etc, just brewed PHP7 installation as an upgrade to the existing PHP 5.5 that comes with Capitan.

Cheers!

Comment: did i miss the error you are getting?  you will always get an error for a self built cert.

Comment: whoops good point, php error: `Fatal error: Uncaught OAuth2\Exception: SSL: CA certificate set, but certificate verification is disabled in /Users/xxx/xxx/xxx/src/vendor/adoy/oauth2/src/OAuth2/Client.php on line 473`

Comment: Also following the documentation to add SSL to Apache I never got an error. It created the crts without errors (that I know of).

Comment: yes, but ssl certs have to be signed by a trusted root authority.  that's why a dozen or so lines of code from godaddy for a cert cost a dozen hamiltons.  did you use a self-built cert that you signed yourself?  it's not possible to buy a cert for localhost.

Comment: Apologies and agreed, It was self built. In the description I provided a link to the article of how I did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After endless hours of testing, configuring, re-installing and hair pulling I finally found the answer.

For everyone experiencing this error I found the end result was the PHP installation. At first I thought it was Auth0 not complying with the SSL Version of Apple's SecureTransport however this was not true.

I upgraded my PHP using cURL into the native directories, changes $PATH variables in profiles and LaunchAgents etc for phpinfo() to show that I was using the updated PHP Version however the modules were actually related to a previous verson and found the PHP installed was looking at its own directories which caused this error (it was not related to a certificate at all).

I rolled back the PHP version to 5.5 that also kept the SecureTransport SSL Version and the cURL requests worked completely fine. I have now finally resolved this issue which was isolated within my localhost environment and happy to share what I did here for anyone else having similar issues you may have experienced.

I cleaned out all installs and Homebrewed all versions of PHP with their own Apache following this guide: [macOS 10.12 Sierra Apache Setup: Multiple PHP Versions](https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-sierra-apache-multiple-php-versions.) Homebrew allows you to install applications such as a complete web environment outside of the main OS directory, therefore causing no impact on its standard installation.

I am using Capitan and this guide still worked without errors. Now I am using PHP 7.1.0RC5 that is using OpenSSL as the default SSL Version and I no longer receive this error. I have tested Auth0 on other PHP installations 5.5,5.6,70 and 71 without fault.

Cheers and again, if you are experiencing this issue, look at your installation, clean it out and reinstall as the default installation when done correctly will prevent this specific error from showing.

New link found for the guide mentioned above if this helps: [macOS 10.12 Sierra Apache Setup: Multiple PHP Versions](https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-sierra-apache-multiple-php-versions)

Please note I am not the owner of the page above, I use it as a guide only.

Comment: The link seems to be dead

Answer (score 1):

Find a way to switch your `curl` code so that if you are in dev `($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=='localhost')` then you set `verifypeer = false` but that doesn't get set and remains true for production.

Comment: I believe this is the only solution that I can also think of. CURL verifypeer would need to be turned off in a dev environment and adding this if statement will force the desired behaviour.

Comment: I do wonder by fixing the first cert as stated in the terminal script would solve my problem and question the doc I used to setup the SSL for apache as it could be outdated when using PHP7? Eitherway this is a solution, not ideal but it works so thank you @WEBjuju

Comment: Unfortunately verifypeer set to false and the entire connection is not in SSL however the error in the callback not changing is an indication that Auth0 is thinking the connection is SSL, requesting further information from the client regarding the certificate which obvioulsy the client is rejecting is causing this error.